# Equivalent to WPF DependencyProperties in Prism ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I understand that the standard way in WPF to expose a custom property in XAML is to define it as `DependencyProperty` in the View’s code-behind.

However, this only works for `DependencyObject`s, such as a `UserControl`. Yet, in clean Prism fashion, my code-behind (i.e., the class deriving from `UserControl`) is empty, and I deal with all the logic in my view model, which derives from `BindableBase`, which is not a child class of `DependencyObject`.

Consider the following XAML fragment:

```
<MyNamespace:MyCustomView MyProperty={Binding} />
```

The core of `MyCustomViewModel` is

```
private string myProperty;
public string MyProperty {
  get { return myProperty; }
  set { SetProperty(ref myProperty, value); }
```

I’m still relatively new to Prism. What do I do to expose a `MyProperty`, which is defined in my `MyCustomViewModel` so that I can set it in XAML with a tag similar to that above?

---

## Update

Following @mm8’s answer and our discussion in the corresponding comments, I developed a minimal (non-)working example of what I have in mind. A summary first:

- Data model is a list of objects.
- Shell must display each of these objects by means of a custom user control for this object type.

### A) The shell

#### A.1) XAML

The XAML is straightforward.

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.Views.MainWindow"
        Name="MainWindowName"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        Title="{Binding Title}" Height="350" Width="525">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StringCollection, ElementName=MainWindowName}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <MyNamespace:MyUserControl MyTargetProperty="{Binding}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

#### A.2) Code-behind

The code-behind contains a data model definition; in reality, I’d define this in the `Models` namespace, of course.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows;

namespace MyProject.Views {
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();

      StringCollection = new ArrayList();
      StringCollection.Add("String 1");
      StringCollection.Add("String 2");
      StringCollection.Add("String 3");
    }

    private ArrayList stringCollection;
    public ArrayList StringCollection {
      get { return stringCollection; }
      set { stringCollection = value; }
    }
  }
}
```

#### A.3) View model

The view model is the standard one provided with the Prism code templates.

```
using Prism.Mvvm;

namespace MyProject.ViewModels {
  public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase {
    private string _title = "Prism Unity Application";
    public string Title {
      get { return _title; }
      set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel() {
    }
  }
}
```

### B) The custom user control

This is where the fun starts. In the end, I’d like to have access to the `MyTargetProperty` in the `MyUserControlViewModel`, since I want to invoke sophisticated program logic on it that depends on other work with the data model, and is thus not to be placed in the code-behind.

#### B.1) XAML

Very naive; only contains a label.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyUserControl"
             Name="UserControlName"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"             
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <Label Content="{Binding MyTargetProperty, ElementName=UserControlName}" Background="AliceBlue"/>
</UserControl>
```

#### B.2) Code-behind

This is where I declare the *target property* as `DependencyProperty`, as suggested in @mm8’s answer.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyProject.Views {
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MyUserControl
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl {
    public MyUserControl() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTargetPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyTargetProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl));
    public string MyTargetProperty {
      get { return (string)GetValue(MyTargetPropertyProperty); }
      set { SetValue(MyTargetPropertyProperty, value); }
    }
  }
}
```

#### B.3) View model

The view model defines the *source property*.

```
using Prism.Mvvm;

namespace MyProject.ViewModels {
  public class MyUserControlViewModel : BindableBase {
    public MyUserControlViewModel() {
    }

    private string mySourceProperty;
    public string MySourceProperty {
      get { return mySourceProperty; }
      set { SetProperty(ref mySourceProperty, value); }
    }
  }
}
```

I can’t for the life of me figure out how to access the values I set in the `MainWindow`’s `ItemTemplate` within the `MyUserControl`’s view model.

Comment: For `MyProperty={Binding}` to work, MyProperty must be a dependency property. You have to declare it in the UserControl's code behind, and there's nothing wrong about that. Having "empty code behind" in a UserControl is pointless. More generally, a UserControl should never have any "own" view model. Instead, a view model instance is usually passed to the UserControl's DataContext (by dependency property value inheritance) from its parent element (e.g. Window).

Comment: Thanks @Clemens, this gives me something to play around with. Using Prism’s `ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"` does internally set the DataContext to a single ViewModel per View, but I agree that this need not be the case in more general approaches. Not sure how to wire a `DependencyProperty` in my code-behind to the ViewModel’s code, though…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only *target* (view) properties must be dependency properties. So for you to be able to bind anything *to* such a property, it must be a dependency property like `MyProperty` in this case:

```
<MyNamespace:MyCustomView MyProperty="{Binding SourceProperty}" />
```

A *source* property in a view model may however be a plain CLR property:

```
public string SourceProperty { get; set; }
```

So your view models don't have to (and shouldn't!) inherit from `DependencyObject` but views should.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you’re saying is in the lines of what @Clemens wrote in his comment above, i.e., define `MyProperty` as `DependencyProperty` in my View’s code-behind. What I don’t see yet, though, is how I can make `MyProperty` available to the program logic I’ve got in the ViewModel without violating MVVM principles. Any thought on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. You *bind* the value of MyProperty of the view to a source property of your view model and handle any logic in the view model where the value of the source property, which is the same as the value of the target property, are available.

Comment: Ah, I see—this sounds feasible. But it appears to be only applicable for target properties set by the user, e.g., the `Text` of a `TextBox`. What happens when I’d like to set `MyProperty` to the iterative element within a `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`? In that case I can’t bind both to the iterative element and the `SourceProperty`, thus breaking the link between view and view model, or am I wrong?

Comment: I still don't understand. You bind a property in the view to a property of the view model and the value then "flows" between the two. It doesn't matter *how* the target property is set. What is your *exact* issue?

Comment: I’ve added an explanatory basic code example to illustrate what I mean. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi @mm8, not to overindulge on your patience, but may I ask you to have a look at the update I posted on my question above? I’m hitting a dead end here, and really do appreciate your help.

Comment: A view model should not access any elements in the view. Then you have completely misunderstood what the MVVM pattern is all about I am afraid. The view model knows nothing about the view.

Comment: So I’m back after an accident that invariably allowed for some time to ponder on this due to not being able to use one hand for typing. :-/ You’re right—I did indeed have a major quirk in my view of things. Also, your answer is absolutely correct, of course. Thank you for being patient when confronted with me being thick as a brick!